# How do I create multiple records in the test data factory of a salesforce test class?

Tags: apex, trigger, test-setup

I have something like this but I want more records of this object to be created to be used in my test class

```
public static Lead createLead(Account new Account)
{
    Lead newLead = new Lead();
    newLead.Account__c = newLead.Id;
    insert newLead;
    return newLead;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the number of records that needs to be created as a parameter to your method and can use that parameter and use for loop to create multiple records.

```
public static List<Legitimation__c> createLegitimation(Account newAccount, Integer numberOfRecords){
    List<Legitimation__c> listLegitimation = new List<Legitimation__c>();
    for(Integer i=0;i<numberOfRecords;i++){
        Legitimation__c newLegitimation = new Legitimation__c();
        newLegitimation.Account__c = newAccount.Id;
        listLegitimation.add(newLegitimation);
    }
    if(!listLegitimation.isEmpty()){
        insert listLegitimation;
     }
    return listLegitimation
}
```

Instead of inserting values in the test data factory itself, it would be better if you could return the list back so that you will still have an option to update the fields back in your test method without needing to use the `update` statement.

So let's say if you want to set another custom field's value in `Legitimation__c` instance which is needed for some of your `testMethods` **and not all**, in that case, you will call your `createLegitimation` method which will return the inserted instance, then you will have to set value of another field and then perform `update` operation on that instance as it is already inserted to database.

Below method just returns the instance without performing the `insert` operation, in this case, you can set the values of other fields which are needed and can directly perform the `insert` operation.

**Note:** Below method does not insert the instances to database, it only returns the instance of it, you will have to call this below method, make any other required changes to that instance and then perform `insert` operation in your `testMethod`

```
public static Legitimation__c createLegitimation(Account newAccount, Integer numberOfRecords){
    List<Legitimation__c> listLegitimation = new List<Legitimation__c>();
    for(Integer i=0;i<numberOfRecords;i++){
        Legitimation__c newLegitimation = new Legitimation__c();
        newLegitimation.Account__c = newAccount.Id;
        listLegitimation.add(newLegitimation);
    }
    return listLegitimation
}
```

Comment: Thanks but can you eloborate on this? what do you mean by without needing to use update statement

Comment: @user3920709 Updated the answer elaborating the same.

Comment: Hi @user3920709, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Done, thanks..I am new to the form, appreciate it

Comment: Yup yup I know.. it was pleasure helping you ! Just that its a good practice to close the question by accepting the answer if it helped. Although there is no obligation to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Vijay's answer with some different coding conventions:

```
private static Legitimation__c[] insertLegitimations(Id parentAccountId, Integer n) {

    Legitimation__c[] legitimations = new Legitimation__c[] {};
    for(Integer i = 0; i < n; i++){
        legitimations.add(new Legitimation__c(
            Account__c = parentAccountId
        ));
    }

    insert legitimations;

    return legitimations
}
```

If your code involves multiple objects, generally better to move this sort of code into a builder/fixture class that can create all the related objects.

Comment: Adding an assert after insert would be perfect.

Comment: Hi @Raul, I don't get why - can you explain more? Any DML error will throw an exception.

Comment: A lot of time dml fails silently and we keep looking for a cause, adding an assert like this in a centralized place reduces hassle.

Comment: Hi @Raul, Not a problem I have experienced but fair point about centralizing assertions.